# is there any set membership of which is not decidable in polynomial time but semidecidable in P?

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, computability, formal-languages

As there are c.e. set and computable set, is there any set membership of which is not decidable in polynomial time  but semidecidable in P? Any reference?

Under the c.e. level that is all set are computable, is there any setsmembership of which is not decidable in NP time  but semidecidable in NP? and are the similar problem in other computational complexity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By semidecidable in P do you mean: Is there a set $X$ with an enumerating machine and a polynomial $p$ such that whenever $n$ is in $X$, the machine enumerates it in time $<p(n)$? If so, that's the same as the set being in P. On the other hand it is common to think of NP as an analogue of r.e. for P.

Comment: thank you, let me think about it.